# Ubuntu16.04 (4.13.16) freeze when shutdown/restart

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, gui, freeze

My ubuntu get freeze when I press shutdown/restart.
Freeze with GUI on, and can not input or move my mouse.
But when I use command `sudo reboot`, it works.
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, kernel 4.13.16

Using `dmesg` command and encounter the only red line:
`[Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0xb2 (or later)`

Comment: what is the output of `dmesg`? Do you see any error in red lines?

Comment: I got a red lines in dmesg return.  
` [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0xb2 (or later) `

Comment: Thanks, my problem sovled after I update my intel-microcode :)

Comment: Using command `sudo apt-get install intel-microcode`

Comment: update your question with those red lines output and then write solution in answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after check output of command `dmesg` inspired by [@Debian_yadav](https://askubuntu.com/users/805078/debian-yadav), figure out my firmware bug. Then update my intel-microcode using command `sudo apt-get install intel-microcode` . It works.